# Another version of recursion theorem

Tags: set-theory

Let $h_1:X\times Y\to X$ and $h_2:X\times Y\to Y$ be functions, and $x\in X, y\in Y$.

Then there exist unique functions $f _1:\mathbb{N}\to X$ and $f_2:\mathbb{N}\to Y$ such that:

$f_1(0)=x$

$f_2(0)=y$

$f_i(n+1)=h_i (f_1(n),f_2(n))$ for each $i=1,2$.

I can use the following recursion theorem:

Let $A$ be a set, $a\in A$ and $g:A\times \mathbb{N}\to A$ a function. Then there exists a unique function $f:\mathbb{N}\to A$ such that $f(0)=a$ and $f(n+1)=g(f(n),n)$

Any hint?

Comment: If you show us what you have tried perhaps someone can use your work to provide a more appropriate hint.

Answer (score 1):

Define a function $F : \mathbb N \to X \times Y$ so that $F(0) = ( x,y )$ and

$$F(n+1) = ( h_1(F(n)) , h_2(F(n)) )$$

using the recursion theorem you have given.

$f_1$ and $f_2$ are simply the first and second components, respectively, of $F$.